# How to generate jQuery template in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, jquery-templates

I want to add input to form dynamically with jQuery templates.

My viewModel for rendering form is listed below

```
public class FormViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Max firstname length is 25 symbols.")]
    [DisplayName("First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Max lastname length is 25 symbols.")]
    [DisplayName("Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "Provide correct email address, please.")]
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Range(16, 150, ErrorMessage = "Age should be between 16 and 150.")]
    [DisplayName("Age")]
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    public IList<DiscountCode> Discounts { get; set; }
}
```

This is my model which I use for inputs that will be created dynamically.

```
public class DiscountCode
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Code name")]
        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Max name length is 10 symbols.")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Code discount")]
        [Integer(ErrorMessage = "The field Percent should be a positive non-decimal number")]
        [Range(1,60, ErrorMessage = "The field Percent should be between 1 and 60.")]
        public int Percent { get; set; }
    }
```

I have this partial view for rendering DiscountCode inputs

```
@using DynamicForm.Models
@model FormViewModel
@if (Model != null && Model.Discounts != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Discounts.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="Discounts.Index" value="@i" />
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Discounts[i].Code, new { @class = "form-control " })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Discounts[i].Code, string.Empty, new { @class = "help-block" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Discounts[i].Percent, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Discounts[i].Percent, new { @class = "form-control " })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Discounts[i].Percent, string.Empty, new { @class = "help-block" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeDiscountRow">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

And for adding discount inputs I use this code snippet

```
var data = { index: lastIndex };
var html = $.templates("#discountRow").render(data);
$(html).appendTo($discountsContainer);
```

and this template

```
<script id="discountRow" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="Discounts.Index" value="{{: index}}">
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Discounts_{{: index}}__Code">Code name</label>
                <input class="form-control " data-val="true" data-val-required="Code is required" data-val-length="Max name length is 10 symbols." data-val-length-max="10"
                       id="Discounts_{{: index}}__Code" name="Discounts[{{: index}}].Code" type="text" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-for="Discounts[{{: index}}].Code" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Discounts_{{: index}}__Percent">Code discount</label>
                <input class="form-control " data-val="true" data-val-required="Percent is required" data-val-number="The field Code discount must be a number."
                       data-val-range="The field Percent should be between 1 and 60." data-val-range-max="60" data-val-range-min="1"
                       data-val-regex="The field Percent should be a positive non-decimal number."
                       data-val-regex-pattern="^-?\d+$" data-val-required="The Code discount field is required."
                       id="Discounts_{{: index}}__Percent" name="Discounts[{{: index}}].Percent" type="text" value="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"
                       aria-describedby="Discounts_{{: index}}__Percent-error">
                <span class="help-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Discounts[{{: index}}].Percent" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeDiscountRow">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

As you can see I just copy output of razor and insert it in template. So if I change validation in model I'll change template each time. How to generate this template automatic with preserving all data attributes for client-side validation ?

Comment: why can't you create variable for validation and pass to view as you would any other data?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate templte code like you create your input code, but Model.Discounts must have at least one element. See code below. I add DiscountCode to discounts if its empty and change some html attributes to make template display as you want;)

```
if (Model.Discounts == null || Model.Discounts.Count <= 0)
{
    Model.Discounts = new List<DiscountCode> { new DiscountCode() };
}
<script id="discountRow" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="Discounts.Index" value="{{: index}}" />
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Discounts[0].Percent, new { @class = "control-label", For = "Discounts[{{: index}}].Code" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Discounts[0].Code, new { @class = "form-control ", Id = "Discounts_{{: index}}__Code", Name = "Discounts[{{: index}}].Code", Value="" } )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Discounts[0].Code, string.Empty, new { @class = "help-block", Data_Valmsg_For = "Discounts[{{: index}}].Code" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Discounts[0].Percent, new { @class = "control-label", For = "Discounts[{{: index}}].Percent" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Discounts[0].Percent, new { @class = "form-control ", Id = "Discounts_{{: index}}__Percent", Name = "Discounts[{{: index}}].Percent", Value = "" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Discounts[0].Percent, string.Empty, new { @class = "help-block", Data_Valmsg_For = "Discounts[{{: index}}].Percent" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeDiscountRow">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```